# Как принимать байты в REST API

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

Как принимать байты в REST API?

Клиент отправляет байты, и не всегда разные JSON объекты. Вопрос, что надо писать в аннотациях `@Produces`, `@Consumes` и в параметрах (надо чтобы он еще отсылал разные JSON объекты)?

Comment: Судя по указанию на аннотации вы используете как-то фреймворк. Какой?

Comment: Не совсем понятна проблема, которая встала перед вами! Что значит не всегда разные, а должны? Что такое анотации `@Produces`, `@Consumes` это может быть из мира `PHP` ? Другими словами точнее сформулируйте свою задачу

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Судя по аннотациям и вашим обычным вопросам, речь о JAX-RS.

Для потока байтов в `@Produces`и `@Consumes` используйте `MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM`.

---

Для приема от клиента в методе используйте параметр типа `InputStream`.

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
public Response getData(InputStream inputStream) {
    // вычитывайте  данные из inputStream
    return Response.ok().build();
}
```

---

Для отдачи клиенту байтов:

- отдавайте байт-массив целиком, если данные доступны заранее и умещаются в память:

  ```
  @GET 
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
  public Response getData() {
      byte[] data = ... ;
      return Response.ok(data).build();
  }
  ```
- либо используйте [`StreamingOutput`](https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/nonav/2.0/apidocs/javax/ws/rs/core/StreamingOutput.html)

  ```
  @GET 
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
  public StreamingOutput getData() {
      return new StreamingOutput() {
          public void write(final OutputStream outputStream) {
           // здесь пишите ваши данные в поток outputStream
          }  
      };
  }
  ```